# Why is 100 in front of 11 in firebase documents order?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm building an app that will display a list of user info, with each one a numeric ID that is stored when creating the profile and used as the docID in firebase. To facilitate the search, I used this method so the ID would be displayed in ascending order. But, after some tests, I notice that, for example, 100 comes first then 11. Why does it happen? Is there a way to correct/prevent it?

I was storing ID as String. But, as the answer suggested, I changed it to both int and double. Still, 11 comes after 100

[image]

Comment: The strings "0", "1", "2", "3", "10", "11" when sorted will be "0", "1", "10", "11", "2", "3". Which is why storing numbers as strings can be tricky. Best to store them as actual numbers so when sorted, they stay stay numerically sorted.

Comment: You are storing strings instead of numbers.  As you can see by everyone's comments and answers here, strings sort differently than numbers.  It would be helpful if you showed your [minimal complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue so we can better explain what specifically you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the answers I got and some research I finally got it.

The main problem was that I was storing the ID as String.

After fixing it, I added .orderBy('id') in the place where I retrieve the
uses' list.

Thank you everyone one for the time spent trying to help me.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say for certain without seeing your database, but most likely you're storing the numbers as strings. In such cases Firebase (both Firestore and Realtime Database) will sort the values [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), and in that order `"100"` comes before `"11"` - just as `"baa"` comes before `"bb"`.

Comment: indeed ID was stored as String. But, just tried storing it as int and then double, still 11 comes after 100

Comment: Can you edit your question to show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That increases the chances we can spot where it is going wrong for you.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is 100 in front of 11 in firebase documents order?

Because you're sorting alphabetically instead of numerically. `0` comes before `1` in most character encodings like ASCII and Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to perform sorting after you queried. It is not efficient though, but in case you cannot change the data type or ids themselves:

```js
const query = await db.collection("my-collection").get();
query.docs.sort((doc1, doc2) => parseInt(doc1.id) - parseInt(doc2.id));
```